# Genetic algorithms: what connection to support vector machine / naive bayes

Tags: classification, svm, naive-bayes-classifier, genetic-algorithms

I found the following list of seven classifiers:

- Linear Classifiers: Logistic Regression, Naive Bayes Classifier
- Nearest Neighbor
- Support Vector Machines
- Decision Trees
- Boosted Trees
- Random Forest
- Neural Network

What are genetic algorithms, and why aren't they considered as part of the seven classifiers?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science Stacke Exchange. To help get a relevant answer for you, could you explain why you think Genetic Algorithms *should* be listed as a classifier (use [edit] to add that information to your question)? After all, there are lots of other technical concepts not included in that list of seven . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast search on Google for the term "Genetic Algorithms" will return you this answer:

***"A genetic algorithm is a search heuristic that is inspired by Charles Darwin's theory of natural evolution"***

So, the term is usually associated with a "search heuristic", for example the search for a local optima.

By that common definition: Genetic Algorithms are not listed among these 7 classifiers since it is not a classifier, it would be in a list of optimization methods like Gradient Descent (and it's variation), Grid Search, Random Search, etc.

Comment: Thank you very well explained also am having issue finding my previous post on here can you help me out.

Comment: You should find all of your answers/questions on your profile activity https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/84373/user11764873?tab=topactivity

If you can't find it, you probably used another account to ask it, try searching it by Title, if you don't find, it might have been deleted.